# Angular: How to spy on $element.on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I have a directive which does something like this in its `link` function

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('barFoo', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, element) {
                element.on('click', ....);
            }
        };
    });
```

Now I would like to verify in my unit test that it calls `on` correctly

```
element = angular.element('<bar-foo></bar-foo>');
$compile(element)(scope);
spyOn(element, 'on');
...
expect(element.on).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

It tells me the spy is not called. From what I've found on the web, angular/jquery creates a new wrapper around the DOM element every time. Meaning the the `element` inside my directive is not the same as the element in my spec file. Most likely (not verified) the `element[0]` probably are the same. I've also tried to spy on `angular.element`

```
var mockEl = { on: angular.noop };
spyOn(angular, 'element').andReturn(mockEl);
spyOn(mockEl, 'on');
```

but that seems to break more than it fixes (I also need functions like `isloateScope` for example).

Anyway, is there some easy way I can spy on the `on` function of the element used inside a directive?

Comment: Why it should be tested in the first place? Click event (as well as other DOM) has to be tested in e2e, and this spec duplicates that in deficient way.

Comment: good point, but what if someone how doesn't understand the component very well, removed it during refactoring. Or based on some logic (wrap it inside an if-statement) it might be useful to test if the binding occurred, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link function can be tested separately

```
element = angular.element('<bar-foo');
spyOn(element, 'on');
BarFooDirective[0].link(scope, element);
expect(element.on).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

if it is simple enough (stays away from attrs, required controllers, dependencies), otherwise the spec will cause more problems than it can solve.

Otherwise, it can be tested [like it is done by the framework](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/test/jqLiteSpec.js#L165):

```
element = angular.element('<bar-foo');
expect(angular.element._data(element[0]).events.click).toBeDefined();
```

For real-world directive which may have more than one `click` listener defined in either itself or child directives it is not enough to make sure that listeners exist. Generally you may want to encapsulate internal functions, but anonymous click handler can also be exposed to scope for the purpose of testing:

```
element = angular.element('<bar-foo');
expect(angular.element._data(element[0]).events.click).toContain(scope.onClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not necessary to test `on` method. You can test event bindings with the help of [`triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)

```
link: function (scope, element) {
    element.on('click', 'something to heppen');
}
```

Test:

```
element = angular.element('<bar-foo></bar-foo>');
$compile(element)(scope); 
$(element[0]).triggerHandler('click');
expect('something binded to click event to happen');
```

Comment: I'm not testing if the `on` method works, I'm testing if it is called and if the right params are passed into it. Your suggestions sound solid!

Answer (score 0):

If you've compiled your element in in a beforeEach like this:

```
myEl = '<div my-el>MY EL</div>';
scope = $rootScope.$new();
directiveElement = $compile(myEl)(scope);
scope.$digest();
```

Try replacing `mousedown` with the event you are testing like this:

```
expect(directiveElement.on.mousedown).toBeDefined;
```