# angularjs + jasmine : testing focus in a service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Learning jasmine for the first time and I am stuck on this error when trying to test the focus() functionality in an angular service. 
Here is the service:

```
myApp.service('MyService', function($timeout, $window) {
  var service = {
    focusElem: focusElem
  };
  return service;

  function focusElem(id) {
    console.log('id of element is = ', id);
    if (id) {

      $timeout(function() {
        var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
        console.log('element is = ', element);
        if (element) {
          element.focus();
        }
      });
    }
  };

});
```

Here is my spec file

```
describe('myApp', function() {
  var element, dummyElement;
  beforeEach(function() {
    // Initialize myApp injector
    module('myApp');

    // Inject instance of service under test    
    inject(function($injector) {
      MyServiceObj = $injector.get('MyService');
    });

    element = angular.element('<input id="firstName" name="firstName"/>');
    dummyElement = document.createElement('input');
    dummyElement.setAttribute('id', 'lastName');

  });

  it('should have focus if the focus Service is used on an element', function() {
    console.info('------------------');
    spyOn(element[0], 'focus');
    spyOn(dummyElement, 'focus');
    MyServiceObj.focusElem(dummyElement.getAttribute('id'));
    expect(dummyElement.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

My error:

```
myApp should have focus if the focus Service is used on an element
Expected spy focus to have been called.
Error: Expected spy focus to have been called.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasmine mock chained methods with Karma and Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285896/jasmine-mock-chained-methods-with-karma-and-angular)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33742298/3731501 if spied `focus` is `callThrough` and triggers focus event.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ngMock` many services are changed so they can be controlled in a synchronous manner within test code to give you more control over the flow.

One of the affected services is `$timeout`.

The function passed to `$timeout` inside your service will not execute in your test unless you tell it to.

To tell it to execute use `$timeout.flush()` like this:

```
spyOn(element[0], 'focus');

spyOn(dummyElement, 'focus');

MyServiceObj.focusElem(dummyElement.getAttribute('id'));

$timeout.flush();

expect(dummyElement.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Note that you need a reference to the `$timeout` service:

```
var element, dummyElement, $timeout;

beforeEach(function() {

  module('myApp');

  inject(function($injector, _$timeout_) {

    MyServiceObj = $injector.get('MyService');

    $timeout = _$timeout_;
  });
```

The next problem is due to the following line in your service:

```
var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
```

The elements you create in your test are never attached to the DOM, so the service will not find them.

The easiest solution is to just attach your elements to the DOM. In this case it's important that you remove them manually after the test, since Jasmine uses the same DOM for your entire test suite.

For example:

```
it('should have focus if the focus Service is used on an element', function() {

  var body = angular.element(document.body);

  body.append(element);
  body.append(dummyElement);

  spyOn(element[0], 'focus');

  spyOn(dummyElement, 'focus');

  MyServiceObj.focusElem(dummyElement.getAttribute('id'));

  $timeout.flush();

  expect(dummyElement.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();

  element.remove();
  dummyElement.remove();
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/F8xqfYYQGa15rwuPPbN2?p=preview

Now, attaching and removing elements to the DOM during unit tests are not always a good thing to do and can get messy.

There are other ways to handle it, for example by spying on `getElementById` and controlling the return value or by mocking an entire document. I won't go into that here however as I'm sure there are examples of it around here already.