# Jasmine - Testing event inside link function of an angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, click, jasmine, document

I have an Angular JS directive. Inside it is a link function. Inside the link function is a click event on document to be checked. Please see code snippet below-

```
link:function(scope,elem,attr) {
    $(document).on("click",function(event){
        //do something 1
        scope.$emit('closeIt');
        scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

Question - I am writing Jasmine test cases. For link function, I am just checking if it returns undefined. This is fine.
I have no clue how to test the `$(document).on("click".... function)`. Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: How to spy on $element.on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738918/angular-how-to-spy-on-element-on)

Comment: Notice that `$document` is there exactly as mockable alternative to `$(document)`.

Comment: If i have something like link: function() { function x() {} how to test x?

Comment: Local function should be exposed to `scope` to be reachable from specs, as in the answer above (`scope.onClick`).